# Simplifying finding a distance along the hypotenuse to travel

Tags: trigonometry

I'm writing a "simulation" of movable "beings". They have a target assigned to them, and each step, they move closer to their target position.

To calculate how far they need to travel each step, I'm using `atan` to calculate the angle that they need to travel at, and `cos`/`sin` to calculate the offset amount in each direction they need to move by.

Example:

If the being is at `[5, 5]`, their target is at `[0, 0]`, and they should move `2` units per step, they should move by `[-1.414 -1.414]` each step to get to their target. I don't want them moving [-5, -5] each step, as that would cause them to "teleport" everywhere.

My problem is the equation I'm using seems very convoluted. I had to partially relearn trig to do this, and I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong; though it gives the correct results.

My basic equation in a pseudo-notation:

```
let pos = [5, 5]
    targ = [0, 0]
    move-by = 2

    x-offset = (x of targ) - (x of pos)
    y-offset = (y of targ) - (y of pos)

    angle = atan(y-offset / x-offset)

    x-move-by = abs(cos(angle)) * signum(x-offset)
    y-move-by = abs(sin(angle)) * signum(y-offset)
```

It's the last two lines I'm concerned about. They give the correct result, but the need to take the absolute value of what `cos` and `sin` return and then multiply by the sign of the offset in each dimension seems odd. I only came about it by tinkering, which of course isn't ideal.

When I simply tried:

```
x-move-by = cos(angle)
y-move-by = sin(angle)
```

I would sometimes get correct results, but it would often cause the being to wander off in the "mirrored" direction.

Is there a simpler way of expressing this?

---

Here's the raw (Clojure) code in case the notation above isn't good:

```
(defn offsets-to-target [position target move-by]
  (let [[x-off y-off] (mapv - target position)
        angle (Math/atan (/ y-off x-off))]

    [(* move-by (Math/abs (Math/cos angle)) (Math/signum ^double x-off))
     (* move-by (Math/abs (Math/sin angle)) (Math/signum ^double y-off))]))
```

Comment: What if the character is at $[0,~ 0]$ and the target is at $[10,~ 5]$? How do they move "two units each step" in this case?

Comment: If you don't want to show the angle somehow, you don't need trigonometry. Just use Pythagoras on `x-offset` and `y-offset`b to scale them

Comment: @law-of-fives It would move by [1.789, 0.894] per tick.

Comment: @N74 Oh, maybe I've over/under thought it through.

Comment: Anyway your expressions derive from the odd expression if atan2: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2 . Atan is not enough to evaluate an angle between two points.

Comment: @N74 Thanks. I don't remember seeing that in Java's Math library, but I'llook again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-using your code in pseudo-notation:

```
let pos = [5, 5]
    targ = [0, 0]
    move-by = 2

    x-offset = (x of targ) - (x of pos)
    y-offset = (y of targ) - (y of pos)

    distance = sqrt(y-offset^2 + x-offset^2)

    x-move-by = x-offset * move-by / distance
    y-move-by = y-offset * move-by / distance
```

In this way you have immediately the correct displacements without calculation for the angle.

You will probably need a test to exclude the case when `distance < move-by`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, another way entirely would be.

distance = sqrt[ (x pos - x start)^2+( y pos - y start)^2]

unit = 2;

steps = distance /unit

x offset =(x pos-x start).steps

y offset = (y pos - y start).steps